# Access Google calendar events from with service account: { "error" : "access_denied" }. No google apps

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I would like to access google calendar using Service account. This is my code :
`<NUMBER>` is replace by the correct value take on Google API Console.

```
<?php

require_once 'googleapi/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'googleapi/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

const CLIENT_ID = '<NUMBER>.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME  = '<NUMBER>@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
const MY_EMAIL  = '<MY NAME>@gmail.com';
const KEY_FILE = 'privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setApplicationName("<APP NAME>");

$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
    $key,
    'notasecret',
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
    MY_EMAIL)
);

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
$calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();

print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";
```

When I execute my code, I receive:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message
>   'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" :
>   "access_denied" }'' in
>   /home/www/65683f67e3f0d94b14bba3c945014cda/web/intranet/googleapi/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:279
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/www/65683f67e3f0d94b14bba3c945014cda/web/intranet/googleapi/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(256):
>   Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array) #1
>   /home/www/65683f67e3f0d94b14bba3c945014cda/web/intranet/googleapi/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(209):
>   Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion() #2
>   /home/www/65683f67e3f0d94b14bba3c945014cda/web/intranet/googleapi/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(166):
>   Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #3
>   /home/www/65683f67e3f0d94b14bba3c945014cda/web/intranet/googleapi/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php(154):
>   Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array) #4
>   /home/www/65683f67e3f0d94b14bba3c945014cda/web/intranet/testService.php(32):
>   Google_CalendarListServiceResource->listCalendarList() #5 {main}
>   thrown in
>   /home/www/65683f67e3f0d94b14bba3c945014cda/web/intranet/googleapi/auth/Google_OAuth2.php
>   on line 279

If I change my code with :

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
$key));
```

I receive:

> (403) Access Not Configured

What is going wrong here?

Comment: ok, I have the solution, but sorry I must wait 2 hours to post it (stackoverflow rules) ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have the solution.
First the good code is the last:

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
      array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
      $key));
```

The problem is not the code, but my google account, I have mentioned a Referer in Google API Console. After erasing the field, the code works.

For information purposes, if you would like to access shared calendars, do not forget to share your calendar with your XXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com (your SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME).

For more information, see:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/kaKYuUstwB0/discussion

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this for a while.. Had no idea I had to give access to my calendar by adding the developer account to it.